# expectException doesn't detect the exception

Tags: yii2, codeception

I am trying to test database records retrieving. My test looks like:

```
use yii\db\Exception;

class UserTest extends Unit
{
    protected $tester;
    private $_user;

    public function _before()
    {
        $this->_user = new User();
    }

    public function testRetrievingFALSE()
    {
       $this->expectException(Exception::class, function(){
          $this->_user->retrieveRecords();
       });
    }
}
```

I saw the `expectException()` method in the [documentation](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Asserts#expectException). My model method looks like this:

```
public function retrieveRecords()
{
    $out = ArrayHelper::map(User::find()->all(), 'id', 'username');
    if($out)
        return $out;
    else
        throw new Exception('No records', 'Still no records in db');
}
```

What am I doing wrong in this scenario?

```
In terminal:
Frontend\tests.unit Tests (1) ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x UserTest: Retrieving false (0.02s)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Time: 532 ms, Memory: 10.00MB

There was 1 failure:

---------
1) UserTest: Retrieving false
 Test  tests\unit\models\UserTest.php:testRetrievingFALSE
Failed asserting that exception of type "yii\db\Exception" is thrown.

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

Comment: It looks like you dot not mock your model and make a real query to database. Are you sure that you do not have any record on database?

Comment: Yup. Totally clear. I am still learning so I made database just for test. 1 table with no records. Will edit the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not using the same method which you're referring to. You should use it on actor instance, not on unit test class itself. So either:

```
$this->tester->expectException(Exception::class, function(){
    $this->_user->retrieveRecords();
});
```

Or in acceptance tests:

```
public function testRetrievingFALSE(AcceptanceTester $I) {
    $I->expectException(Exception::class, function(){
        $this->_user->retrieveRecords();
    });
}
```

If you call it on `$this` in test class, method from PHPUnit will be used, which works differently:

```
public function testRetrievingFALSE() {
    $this->expectException(Exception::class);
    $this->_user->retrieveRecords();
}
```

See more examples in [PHPUnit documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.exceptions.examples.ExceptionTest.php).